# Load PHP file after progress bar complete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get my progress bar to update with the actual PHP code when completed.

```
var url2 = '';
function progressBarSim(al) {

  var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.innerHTML = al+"%";
  bar.value = al;
  al++;
  var elem = document.getElementById("progressBar"); 
  elem.style.width = al + '%'; 
  var sim = setTimeout("progressBarSim("+al+")",77);
    if(al == 100){
      status.innerHTML = "100%";
      bar.value = 100;
      clearTimeout(sim);
      var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');

      finalMessage.innerHTML = "<?php include('hi.php'); ?>";
    }
}
var amountLoaded = 0;
progressBarSim(amountLoaded);
```

The above code works when I don't include PHP code inside my `hi.php` file but if I include any form of actual PHP code inside the file it will just make my entire progress bar not work anymore. How can I make my progress bar load hi.php when it's reached 100%?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access files, located on server via client javascript.
Moreover, all php scripts are running on server side.

UPD:

{

In your case you can do these things:

1)Load content that you want to show with other page - it's fit, if loading content does not vary.

2)Load content dynamically, using AJAX

}

If you want to load content dynamically, you should read about ajax queries.